# Facing issues with retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I am trying to parse this json response using retrofit and Kotlin in MVVM.

```json
{
   "statusCode":200,
   "status":true,
   "dataObject":[
      {
         "myHierarchy":[
            {
               "heirarchyList":[
                  {
                     "contactName":"name1",
                     "contactNumber":"9182928292",
                     "designationName":"desgination1"
                  },
                  {
                     "contactName":"name1",
                     "contactNumber":"9182928292",
                     "designationName":"desgination1"
                  },
                  {
                     "contactName":"name1",
                     "contactNumber":"9182928292",
                     "designationName":"desgination1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my `ViewModel` I am trying to implement MVVM and dagger

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class RetrofitViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {
    var liveDataList: MutableLiveData<List<User>>
    val movieItemm: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()

    init {
        liveDataList = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun getLiveDataObserver(): MutableLiveData<List<User>> {
        return liveDataList
    }



    fun makeAPICall() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = repository.remote.getApiMovies()
            response.enqueue(object : Callback<UserModel> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<UserModel>,
                    response: Response<UserModel>
                ) {
                   response.body()?.dataObject?.forEach {
                       it?.myHierarchy?.forEach {
                           it?.heirarchyList?.forEach {
                               it?.contactName
                           }
                       }
                   }

                    Log.d("Response", "${response.body()}")

/*response.body()?.dataObject.let {  item->
    item?.forEach { it->
        it?.myHierarchy?.forEach { i->
         i?.heirarchyList?.forEach { us->
             us?.designationName

         }
        }
    }
}*/

                    val movies: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()

                    liveDataList.postValue(movies)
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModel>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure, $call, $t")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the details of the user but `dataObject` is always `null`.

Comment: What you're getting in the log  Log.d("Response", "${response.body()}")

Comment: include your data classes as well

Comment: Where is your data class?